# How to load a html project onclick in django project

Tags: html, ajax, django

I am developing a `django` project. I have two html files- `sid.html` and `page2.html`. Main page is `sid.html`. On click on a div, i want to load another page `page2.html`,fully on my window(not in div).I tried out `ajax`, `jquery` but it doesnt seem to work. May i know how to go ahead and the changes to be done in views,urls. Please help.

Comment: "it doesnt seem to work.", what doesn't? what isn't working? what happens? errors?

Comment: you edit and paste what is wrong, starting from your html page, views.py and urls.py

Comment: <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
     $(function() {
     $("#megha").click(function() {
      var url = 'page2.html';
$(location).attr('href', url);
   })
    });
    });
      </script>

Comment: above is my js function.

Comment: 'megha' is the id of the div onclick of which the html page- page2.html should load.

Comment: page2 .html is in the same page as main html page...Is there any other method like shud we change something in views.py or urls.py?

Comment: Made some format edits

Answer (score 0):

With out seeing all of your code no we cant but in the most basic way of doing it would be this.

URLs

`url(r'^page2/$', 'YourAppName.views.page2'),`

views

`def page2(request):
    return render(request, 'page2.html')`

in the html you could do this

`<div class="myclass" href="/page2/">`

or as a js script

`<div onclick="location.href='/page2/'">content</div>`

or even JQ

`$("div").click(function(){
   window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;
});`

with this in your HTML

`<div><a href="yourlinkhere">Your link text</a></div>`

hope this helps, they will have to be tweeked to fit the names of your files and such but its a starting block

Comment: so the html code for page 2 is i the same file as sid?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that this is your url

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    #other url
    url(r'^page2/$', 'YourAppName.views.page2'),
)
```

Now you said "Onclick on a div, i want to load another page page2.html,fully on my window(not in div).I tried out ajax, jquery". Assuming this is your div which you are to click `<div class="myclass"></div>`.

```js
function newDoc() {
    window.location.assign("http://www.example.com") // {% url 'yourapps.views.page2' %} the django reverse style
    //always to remember to add 'http' protocol to any url you will use apart from  the django reverse style else you will get Server Error 
}
```

```html
<div onclick="newDoc()" style="background-color:yellow; height: 20px; cursor:pointer;"></div>
```